# Standard location for a WSDL file

Tags: java, maven, wsdl2java

In a maven based project, what is the standard location to place a WSDL file which will be used to generate source files using wsdltojava?
Is it under the resources or there is another path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [wsdl2java maven plugin](http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/maven/wsdl2java/) does not specify a default location for a WSDL file.

However, if you're going to ship your jar file with an included WSDL the JAX-WS specs generally indicate that `META-INF/wsdl/` is a good place for such files. In your case, this would be `resources/META-INF/wsdl/`.